# Fortran90 : Understanding of function testing the presence or the value of input file paramter

Tags: fortran, boolean, gfortran, fortran90

I have an issue concerning the value of a parameter of an input file in `Fortran90` :

the part of input file concerned is :

```
# If use_phyical set physical densities in baryons, CDM and neutrinos + Omega_k
use_physical   = F
ombh2          = 0.022445
omch2          = 0.12055785438700001
omnuh2         = 0.000645145613
omk            = 0.0
hubble         = 67.0

#if use_physical = F set parameters as here
omega_baryon   = 0.05
omega_cdm      = 0.2685627651944076
omega_lambda   = 0.6800000648055924
omega_neutrino = 0.00143717
```

and the parameter that implies issue is `use_physical` that I want to set to `F` by default for every run (indeed, I do several runs by making vary the `omega_cdm` parameter).

Below the part of code that reads the input parameters (see above).

```
write(*,*) '0) Ini%Read_Double use_physical = ', Ini%Read_Logical('use_physical', .false.)
if (Ini%Read_Logical('use_physical', .false.) .eqv. .false.) then
    write(*,*) '1.1) Ini%Read_Double use_physical = ', Ini%Read_Logical('use_physical', .false.)
    P%ombh2 = Ini%Read_Double('omega_baryon')*(P%H0/100)**2
    P%omch2 = Ini%Read_Double('omega_cdm')*(P%H0/100)**2
    P%omnuh2 = Ini%Read_Double('omega_neutrino')*(P%H0/100)**2
    P%omk = ((P%H0/100)**2 - P%ombh2 - P%omch2 - P%omnuh2 - Ini%Read_Double('omega_lambda')*(P%H0/100)**2)/(P%H0/100)**2
    write(*,*) 'Computing with use_physical = false'
    write(*,*) '1.2) Ini%Read_Double use_physical = ', Ini%Read_Logical('use_physical', .false.)
else
    write(*,*) '2) Ini%Read_Double use_physical = ', Ini%Read_Logical('use_physical', .false.)
    P%ombh2 = Ini%Read_Double('ombh2')
    P%omch2 = Ini%Read_Double('omch2')
    P%omnuh2 = Ini%Read_Double('omnuh2')
    P%omk = Ini%Read_Double('omk')
end if
```

At the execution of program above, if I set `use_physical   = F`, I get the following output (with different `write(*,*)` that I have used) :

```
 0) Ini%Read_Double use_physical =  F
 1.1) Ini%Read_Double use_physical =  F
 Computing with use_physical = false
 1.2) Ini%Read_Double use_physical =  F
```

I don't understand the value of `Ini%Read_Logical('use_physical', .false)` : If `use_physical = F`, this should be equal to `TRUE` boolean, shouldn't it ?

Why  this following condition is equal to true with `use_physical = F` :

```
if (Ini%Read_Logical('use_physical', .false.) .eqv. .false.)
```

For me, this should be rather :

1)    `if (Ini%Read_Logical('use_physical', .false.) .eqv. .true.)`

or an equivalent :

2)    `if (Ini%Read_Logical('use_physical', .false.))`

with 1) and 2) meaning both that `use_physical = F` : but the ouput of `write(*,*)` above seems to say the contrary : the condition `if (Ini%Read_Logical('use_physical', .false.) .eqv. .false.)` is true when `use_physical = F`.

Question 1) I don't understand, if anyone could find an explaination to this problem.

Question 2) From your point of view, what's the type returned by :

```
Ini%Read_Logical('use_physical', .false.)
```

I tried to use the conditions :

```
if (Ini%Read_Logical('use_physical', .false.) == 'T')
```

or

```
 if (Ini%Read_Logical('use_physical', .false.) .eq. .true)
```

But I get compilation errors

PS : Sorry, I didn't find for instant the implementation of `Ini%Read_Logical`routine but this would be logic to say that `Ini%Read_Logical('use_physical', .false.)` is true when `use_physical = F` and not the contrary.

**UPDATE 1 :** I think that I found the definition of the function `Ini%Read_Logical` :

```
function Ini_Read_Logical(this, Key, Default)
class(TIniFile) :: this
logical Ini_Read_Logical
logical, optional, intent(IN) :: Default
character(LEN=*), intent(IN) :: Key
character(LEN=:), pointer :: S
integer status

S => this%Read_String(Key,.not. present(Default))
if (S == '') then
    call this%EmptyCheckDefault(Key,Default)
    Ini_Read_Logical = Default
    call  this%ReadValues%Add(Key, Default)
else
    if (verify(trim(S),'10TF') /= 0) then
        status=1
    else
        read (S,*, iostat=status) Ini_Read_Logical
    end if
    if (status/=0) call this%Error('error reading logical',Key)
end if

end function Ini_Read_Logical
```

But this is a little tricky to understand.

Do you understand better why, At the execution of program above, if I set `use_physical   = F`, I get the following output (with different `write(*,*)` that I have used)  ? :

```
 0) Ini%Read_Double use_physical =  F
 1.1) Ini%Read_Double use_physical =  F
 Computing with use_physical = false
 1.2) Ini%Read_Double use_physical =  F
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think "this would be logic to say that Ini%Read_Logical('use_physical', .false.) is true when use_physical = F and not the contrary"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user provides a value in the ini file, the function Ini%Read_Logical returns what that value is interpreted to be as a LOGICAL.  If the user provides no value, the function Ini%Read_Logicalreturns the value of the default argument (the second actual argument in the references to the procedure binding).

You provide a value of "F in the ini file, which is interpreted as .FALSE. ("F" is the first letter of "False"), so Ini%Read_Logical returns .FALSE..  The value of the default argument is not used.

.FALSE. .EQV. .FALSE. is true, so the code executes the block of statements immediately following the if statement.

The type of the value returned by Ini%Read_Logical is LOGICAL.  To compare logical values you use the .EQV. operator (short for "logical equivalence"), or .NEQV. ("not equivalent").  The == and /= intrinsic operators used for the numeric and character types are not defined.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, if I have well understood, setting `use_physical = F`   or setting nothing will give the same result, i.e `Init%Read_Logical` will return `.FALSE.` , won't it ? On the contrary, setting `use_physical = T` will execute the `else`of my condition `if   then else` block of my original question ? Regards